# Mysqli - Order table A by input from table B

Tags: php, mysqli

I am puting an ajax sort button on my page. I want to sort accomodation object by highest price, but I have another table for price because each unit has a different price range by dates.
Here is my Accomodation table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Accomodation` (
  `SmjestajID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SmjestajNaziv` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SmjestajTip` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SmjestajKategorija` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SmjestajAdresa` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`SmjestajID`)
)
```

And here is my Price table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Price` (
  `SmjestajCjenikID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SmjestajCjenikRazdoblje` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SmjestajCjenikCijena` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SmjestajID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SmjestajCjenikID`)
)
```

With this query I get to sort accomodation objects by highest price but only accomodation objects who have price inserted, what about ones who still have no price inserted, they should be put last like cheapest.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Accomodation.*, max(CONVERT(Price.SmjestajCjenikCijena,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) 
FROM Accomodation 
INNER JOIN Price ON Accomodation.SmjestajID = Price.SmjestajCjenikSmjestaj 
GROUP BY Price.SmjestajCjenikSmjestaj 
ORDER BY max(CONVERT(Price.SmjestajCjenikCijena,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Accomodation.*, max(CONVERT(Price.SmjestajCjenikCijena,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) 
FROM Accomodation 
INNER JOIN Price ON Accomodation.SmjestajID = Price.SmjestajCjenikSmjestaj 
GROUP BY Price.SmjestajCjenikSmjestaj 
ORDER BY max(CONVERT(Price.SmjestajCjenikCijena,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) DESC
HAVING Price.SmjestajCjenikCijena > 0
```

Comment: I try your code, but still have same problem, only showing objects with price inserted.